# error when importing local google fonts with sass new version

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, less, scss-mixins

i am trying to add new google fonts to some sass files , these fonts are local fonts and i am adding them using sass and url using the following code

```
    @font-face
    font-family: 'Abril Fatface'
    font-style: normal
    font-weight: 400
    src: url('abril-fatface-v9-latin-regular.eot')
    src: local('Abril Fatface'), local('AbrilFatface-Regular'),
        url('abril-fatface-v9-latin-regular.eot?#iefix')
            format('embedded-opentype'),
        /* IE6-IE8 */ url('abril-fatface-v9-latin-regular.woff2')
            format('woff2'),
   url('abril-fatface-v9-latin-regular.woff')
            format('woff'),
 url('abril-fatface-v9-latin-regular.ttf')
            format('truetype'),

            url('abril-fatface-v9-latin-regular.svg#AbrilFatface')
            format('svg')





    Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
    SassError: expected ":".
      ╷
    7 │         url('abril-fatface-v9-latin-regular.eot?#iefix')
      │            ^
      ╵
      src/modules/editor/styles/fonts/abril-fatface-v9-latin/index.sass 7:12  @import
      src/modules/editor/styles/fonts/fonts.sass 1:9                          @import
      src/modules/editor/styles/index.sass 10:9                               root stylesheet
```

Comment: You could try to remove the ie-specific urls `url('abril-fatface-v9-latin-regular.eot?#iefix')` – your sass compiler might have issues with the `?#` query var. I'd also try to remove all comments. BTW: you can safely remove .eot rules – unless you really need ie8 support

Comment: @herrstrietzel still getting error,any idea how can i fix it ? ``@font-face
    font-family: 'Abril Fatface'
    font-style: normal
    font-weight: 400
    src: url('./abril-fatface-v9-latin-regular.eot')
    src: local('Abril Fatface'), local('AbrilFatface-Regular')
         url('./abril-fatface-v9-latin-regular.woff2') format('woff2')
         url('./abril-fatface-v9-latin-regular.woff') format('woff')
         url('./abril-fatface-v9-latin-regular.ttf') format('truetype')
         url('./abril-fatface-v9-latin-regular.svg#AbrilFatface') format('svg')``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
@font-face 
    font-family: 'Abril Fatface'
    font-style: normal
    font-weight: 400
    src: url('abril-fatface-v9-latin-regular.woff2') format('woff2'), url('abril-fatface-v9-latin-regular.woff') format('woff')
```

I removed whitespace (newlines, tabs) between different urls.
Since **Sass is whitespace-sensitive** (in contrast to scss), the previously used new lines seem to break parsing the src property.